# Como funciona a parte do Front-end com OAuth 2.0?

Tags: laravel, front-end, oauth

Eu fiz toda a parte necessária do back-end pra usar o OAuth e a api já retorna o access_token e o refresh_token, minha dúvida é, o que é necessário fazer no front-end (se possível com exemplos).

Toda requisição primeiro vou ter que verificar se o token não expirou, caso sim, gerar um novo token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependendo da maneira que você for utilizar não é necessário ficar autenticando sempre que ele expira. A 2 meses atrás eu implementei a API do Gmail(Gsuite) no meu site. Depois do processo de autenticação me foi gerado um arquivo que salva as informações para que eu não precise ficar renovando a mesma.

Caso você vá utilizar varias contas de acesso, acredito que seja necessário armazenar um arquivo para cada usuário. No meu caso eu apenas utilizo uma ,que é a minha conta "bussines" do Gmail.

Tive essa mesma duvida e mandei um ticket para o Google, segue a resposta(ela pode ser aplicada no seu caso pois Oauth):

> O token de acesso do Gmail tem sim uma validade de 3600 segundos, ou uma hora, e deve ser atualizado sempre que o token expira. Para que o usuário não tenha que ficar autenticando a aplicação a cada hora, tu podes implementar o que é chamado de Server-side Authorization que utiliza as informações salvas do usuário para renovar o token de acesso e com isso não interromper o funcionalmento da aplicação.